# IOS: Can not install our app from Appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Our new IOS app was updated to Appstore successful yesterday.
Some users can update normally but the others not.
Include myself, we can see Appstore is downloading our app,so do the icon on desktop.
But when downloaded the icon of our app disappear.
It seems that the app was not installed.
Some 6 and 6s users have this question.

Our app is passed by Appstore, and some user can download and install it.
The package seems worked.
Why the app can not be installed in some users' IPHONE?

Comment: How can we know? Ask Apple. As long as it can start downloading, it should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally catch the problem.

Because of the pool network, we retried a few times updating the package.
At the last time, we choose the wrong package with lower version code in Info.plist.

The package had a lower code, but may apple keep a higher version code for verification.

We get a lot of 1stars caused by this which made us upset.

I don't understand why Apple put it to AppStore in such a case.

Anyway, please be careful at package updating.

Answer (score 1):

No issues with you code as well as your package info. Yesterday Apple had issue with their server. [image]

Refer this [link](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If app is installed without any issue & in some device its not than there might be few possible reasons like below:

- First possible reason is Minimum IOS version set in the App is higher than the device OS version. Let say for ex: In your App you have set the Minimum iOS version to 9.0. And users who are not able to install will running of less than 9.0.
- Second possible reason is Architecture support. May be your app not supporting arm 64 support & due to that it will not allowing to install on arm64 based devices.

Now in your case i strongly believe there will be minimum iOS version issue. Why less chances of second issue is as you know now arm64 support is compulsory in iOS Apps. Otherwise Apple will reject your app.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: em...the mininum is ios7.0, it may not cause by this. We also add support to arm 64. Most of users use 6 and 6s in ios9. But some phone is normal and the other not. We did not find the difference yet.